# NSURL code to display an image from a sqlite table

Tags: iphone, sqlite, uiimage, nsurl

Ii'm using this NSURL code to display an image. what I want to do is to insert a url from my database table in place of the static url shown in the code below:

Does anyone know how I should proceed?

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.nyapplecountry.com/images/photosvarieties/redrome04.jpg"];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]]; 
[self.view addSubview:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image]];
[self.containerView addSubview:self.mainView];
```

I was thinking of something like:

```
NSString *urlAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", place.url];
```

where `place.url` is coming from my db table. I'm missing something though, not sure what.

thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `place.url` a `NSString object` and the full URL to the image? Then it would be as simple as

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:place.url]; 
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
```

Comment: place.url is the full URL to the image. that works perfectly. thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it that way. You have to read image from data base and initialize UIImage with that data.